# How to set a custom icon in dataview with bootstrap theme

Tags: css, icons, xpages, dataview

I want to set a custom icon with glyphicons or custom uploaded icon on xpages dataview, but the icon always defaults to file icon. Im using bootstrap theme and latest xpages extension lib (r10).

I want to change the icon in the dataview document row, not the categorization icon. The code with bootstrap theme always defaults to this code.

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-file xspReadIcon"></div>
```

I tried with:

```
<xe:iconEntry selectedValue="read" url="/legalforms.gif" styleClass="hidden-xs"></xe:iconEntry>
<xe:iconEntry selectedValue="read" url="/legalforms.gif" styleClass="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></xe:iconEntry>
```

Comment: You should really provide more detail. What have you tried? Some code snippets? That kind of thing. I will post an answer below shortly in any case, but for future reference your question should have more detail

Comment: I want to change the icon in the dataview document row, not the categorization icon. The code with bootstrap theme always defaults to this code.

<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-file xspReadIcon"></div>

I tried with:
<xe:iconEntry selectedValue="read" url="/legalforms.gif" styleClass="hidden-xs"></xe:iconEntry>
and
<xe:iconEntry selectedValue="read" url="/legalforms.gif" styleClass="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></xe:iconEntry>

Comment: Thank you. With that extra info I was able to investigate further and found a bug in the data view renderer for the bootstrap theme. Will look into a fix for that for a future extlib release. In the meantime, I've updated my answer below so you could use that as a workaround, instead of using the iconColumn.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've found a bug in the data view renderer for the bootstrap theme. We will look into fixing that in the future. In the meantime you can try using the workaround below.

You can use the icon facet of the data view, by specifiying `xp:key="icon"`. Then add a div with a custom styleClass in the facet. For example:

```
<xe:dataView id="dataView1">
    ....
    <xe:this.facets>
      <xp:panel xp:key="icon">
        <xp:div>
             <xp:this.styleClass>
                 <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                     var doc:NotesDocument = viewEntry.getDocument();
                     if(doc.getRead()) {
                         return "hidden-xs";
                     }else{
                        return "glyphicon glyphicon-user";
                     }
                }]]>
            </xp:this.styleClass>
        </xp:div>
      </xp:panel>
    </xe:this.facets>
</xe:dataView>
```

Comment: Brian, I ran across this post, and it works great for me, except I need to have TWO icons horizontally - I posted a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755222/how-to-set-a-2-custom-icon-in-dataview-with-bootstrap-theme

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Brians solution and that may work for you,  I could however not get it to work for the category icon.

anyway, You can replace all icons client side by replacing the icons on load, 
you may need to call the code on partial refresh also

```
$(function(){
$(".glyphicon-minus-sign").removeClass("glyphicon-minus-sign").addClass("glyphicon-minus")
$(".glyphicon-plus-sign").removeClass("glyphicon-plus-sign").addClass("glyphicon-plus")
})
```

Comment: By the way, you should be able to get it working on the category icon by using `xp:key="categoryRow"` I think, in case you were trying "category"

Comment: Ok, good. is there somewhere we can see a list of all the facet keys for different controls in extlib?

Comment: 2 things I can think of: there is tooltip hover help in the All Properties tab for a control. For instance, hovering `categoryColumn` brings up a tooltip: "Note that the category columns may also be defined in facet controls....". Second, generally in the `Design` tab you can see facets marked there (I presume most people work in the source tab so might miss that). Check out the Design tab for Application Layout control for instance, and you can see facets such as `LeftColumn` & `RightColumn` and a few others. Don't think we have a full list of facets for all controls listed anywhere though.